# Kentico radio buttons render

Tags: radio-button, kentico

I have radio buttons in horizontal layout on my Kentico CMS site. they looking good, but when i use more than 5 product options they start ruin whole site structure, is it possible render them in few rows? Something like if there are more than 5 items others will be placed in next row.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default. You have to write your own form control to render the items in this way.

See the [documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?developing_form_controls.htm) on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Kentico CMSRadioButtonList You can use 
RadioButtonName.RepeatColumns=x;